# How to fix border for map in mapkit with custom overlay method

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit

I am working with mapkit application.In it I have made custom overlay for get detail about specific location when I touched that location.In it at when I touch at map's border location I get image out of map view bound.(gray image which is out of map view).So would you suggest me how can I make it in map's bound and how can I handle it.

Thank you all.